# Android 5.0(Lollipop): Material Style Not Being Applied

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-theme

I'm trying to make my app fit with Google's best practices for material design but for some reason the items I set in my v21\styles.xml are never applied to my application.

Please take a look at the v21 styles and Android Manifest files below and tell me what I'm doing wrong that would cause my custom AppTheme to not show up.

**v21\styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- android theme colors -->
        <!-- Main theme colors -->
        <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#F44336</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FFD600</item>
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#FFD600</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.foo"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="12"
            android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">   **Theme set here**
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    <!-- Test:USB otg  -->
                    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
                </intent-filter>
                <!-- Test:USB otg  -->
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" 
                    android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

I'm testing this code on a device that runs the most recent version of Android, API 23, so i'm not sure why the styles for API 21+ wouldn't be triggered.

Below I have also posted my App's style xml files for other platform versions, it seems that one of these is being used by the app instead. I have included these for completeness.

**v14\styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

**v11\styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--
        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.

    -->
   <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**values\styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.

    -->

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">@style/ButtonBar</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">@style/ButtonBarButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ButtonBar">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/bottom_bar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ButtonBarButton" />
</resources>
```

Why is my app never displaying the style I have laid out in v21\styles.xml??

Comment: How do you know that v21 theme is not being used? Android will search for themes attributes in v21 and if a style is not set, android then looks for the attribute in default theme (in res/values/styles.xml).. Im asking just to get more information to help you

Comment: I know the v21 theme isn't being used because the status bar is black instead of the gold hue I set in the "colorPrimaryDark" item. Additionally, I'm confident the v21 theme isn't used because I've tried changing the name of this theme to "CustomTheme" and setting the application's theme to "android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">" and the status bar is still black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error.

Basically, in your Manifest File, you are setting "AppTheme" for application. However, you are also setting a Theme for the activity (FullscreenTheme).

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    <application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">   **Theme set here**
        <activity
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        ...               
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

To Fix, I see two options:

**Option1:**

You can remove:

```
android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"
```

**Option2:**

If you really need to use that FullscreenTheme, added it to v21/styles.xml. Then, you can set it diferently in v21.

It is your call!

Comment: Thanks, it works. Buttons and menu items follow the theme now. For some reason my status bar is gold when the app is launching but then turns black again once the app is initialized. Any idea what would cause this?

Comment: Which fix did you applied?  Did you removed FullscreenTheme from manifest file?

Comment: Correct: the fullscreen theme is removed from my code entirely.

Comment: Even then the issue that you mentioned is happening?

Comment: Yes. And surpisingly, the app is still acting fullscreen (not showing the status bar unless it's directly touched) even though i removed the reference to it.

Comment: This happens because "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" is the parent theme of your AppTheme. Change it to "Theme.AppCompat.Light" or use any other parent theme

Comment: So there is no way to customize the color of the status bar while using a "fullscreen" parent theme?

Comment: I think it is not possible because in Fullscreen mode, the status bar becomes transparent (or almost transparent). You can change the color of actionBar (or toolbar) but the status bar (notification bar) will be transparent.